# Find tables with specific columns across databases in snowflake?

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is a resource that provides a query to find tables with a specific column name in snowflake: https://dataedo.com/kb/query/snowflake/find-tables-with-specific-column-name

However, when I use this query, I'm finding that it's only searching one database, and I don't know how to specify which database(s) to search....

Tips?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you simply want to specify WHICH database to query, you can fully-qualify the reference to the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` view as follows:

```
select t.table_schema, 
       t.table_name
from DATABASE_NAME_TO_SEARCH.information_schema.tables t
inner join information_schema.columns c on 
       c.table_schema = t.table_schema and c.table_name = t.table_name
where t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
       and column_name ='N_NAME'
order by t.table_schema, 
       t.table_name;
```

If you want to scan across ALL databases within a Snowflake account, you can do it with the following PAIR of commands:

```
SHOW COLUMNS LIKE 'COLUMN_NAME_HERE' IN ACCOUNT
;
SELECT "database_name" AS TABLE_DB
      ,"schema_name" AS TABLE_SCHEMA
      ,"table_name" AS TABLE_NAME
  FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
 WHERE "kind" = 'COLUMN'
 ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
;
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use the database `SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE`:

```sql
select table_schema, table_name, column_name
from snowflake.account_usage.columns
where deleted is null
and column_name='RIP4'
```

Most users don't have access to it, so you might need to grant the privileges first:

```sql
use role accountadmin;
grant imported privileges on database snowflake to role sysadmin;
```

> https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to get the tables that contain a specific column name is the following:

```
show columns like 'COLUMN_NAME' in schema "DB_NAME"."SCHEMA_NAME"
```

In the above example, we search for all tables under the database "DB_NAME" and under the schema "SCHEMA_NAME" that contain the column called "COLUMN_NAME".

You can have a look at the [Show Columns](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-columns.html) Snowflake Documentation. The full syntax is:

```
SHOW COLUMNS [ LIKE '<pattern>' ]
             [ IN { ACCOUNT | DATABASE [ <database_name> ] | SCHEMA [ <schema_name> ] | TABLE | [ TABLE ] <table_name> | VIEW | [ VIEW ] <view_name> } ]
```

Note that if you specify the keyword ACCOUNT, then the command retrieves records for all schemas in all databases of the current account.

Source: [Predictive Hacks](https://predictivehacks.com/?all-tips=how-to-find-tables-that-contain-a-specific-column-in-snowflake)